# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' when installing mySql on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lamp

I'm setting up my own website for the first time and I'm using this tutorial: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

Now after installing MySql the first time I had some kind of error later on so I rebuilt the droplet and started again. Now everything is going well I get to installing mySql and after trying:

```
$ mysql_secure_installation
```

It asks for my root password and after that I can en error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I just can't access it anyway. Is there a possible way to start installing everything from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

The default root password is blank (i.e. empty string) not root. So you can just log in as:

```
mysql -u root
```

You should obviously change your root password after installation

```
mysqladmin -u root password [newpassword]
```

In most cases, you should also set up individual user accounts before working extensively with the DB as well.